# Scraping Data from NHL.com

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I'm trying to grab the table from http://www.nhl.com/ice/standings.htm?season=20112012&type=LEA, and store it into a MySQL database on my server. Using the below, I'm able to copy the website exactly, but I'm not sure how to just extract that table. Code below:

Any ideas?

```
function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://www.nhl.com/ice/standings.htm?season=20112012&type=LEA');

echo $returned_content;
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.nhl.com/ice/standings.htm?season=20112012&type=LEA');
    $e = $html->find("table", 2);

    echo($e);
```

This code works, posts a table like the one I need. But Now I'm curious as to how I would go about stripping all unnecessary links/formatting and saving it to the database?

Comment: This is probably against their TOS. Companies make a lot of money providing webservices and APIs for this data.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with this library
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Tried that as well. Didn't get anywhere near as far as I did with cURL. It's hard because I can't find a decent tutorial out there for me to get started with this, even though what I want to do is advanced.

Answer (score 0):

In google spreadsheets, all my `importhtml` functions to nhl.com do not work this year. I think they are (for some reason) blocking users from scraping their data.